# Cannot connect to an ad hoc wireless connection setup on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, mobile-phone

I have already gone through a bunch of questions here on superuser regarding ad hoc connectivity, but couldn't find one that covered my situation.

**The Setup**

I have a Windows 7 laptop that we want to enable as a wireless gateway at a conference booth, allowing people free access to our online product while they near the booth (since we would identify the laptop as the gateway).

Anyway, I've plugged in a USB NetComm NP545 wireless adapter into the laptop (which already has an Intel PROset built in) and configured a connection on this adapter to act as an *ad hoc* network using WPA2 security.

I've also enabled internet sharing on the connection setup on the primary adapter.

**The Problem**

When it came to testing the ad hoc network, we've encountered a variety of problems.

Firstly, two different Android devices (4.0 and 2.3) and an iPad cannot even discover the device.

Secondly, a Nokia N97 and another laptop can discover the network, but cannot login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Phones have a hard time connecting to ad-hoc networks. An access point works best. Try [Connectify.](http://www.connectify.me/) I use it and think it is quite good. There is another [Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/272961/how-does-connectify-work) which explains how it works.

Comment: Thanks - I've downloaded Connectify and have setup the laptop as an access point. The best thing is that once configured, the conference guys will only have to "start" the hotspot - wish I hadn't spent so much time figuring out the Windows ad hoc settings now