# How to Create WiFi Hotspot with Single Adapter in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter, hotspot, wifi-configuration, virtual-wifi

I know how to create a hotspot when connected to a wired network, but when I am using internet from a WiFi connection, this disconnects the wireless connection the moment I activate the hotspot.

In Windows I can use [Connectify Hotspot](http://www.connectify.me/hotspot/), which enables me to share the internet connection from the same wireless adapter as I am creating an access point on. As you can read on the [technology overview page](http://www.connectify.me/wifi-hotspot-technology-overview/):

***Access Point mode allows you to create a Hotspot using the same Wi-Fi card that you are using to access the Internet.***

NB: I have been connected with Connectify me successfully from my PC, but due to trial version it is now not working. I think if Connectify me can do that, there must be a way.

Please help if anybody know the way. I have tried many ways from internet but due to single adapter my PC failed.Then how Connectify me managed from the same PC with the same adapter?

Comment: Uhmm, why not just buy Connectify?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Connectify work?](http://superuser.com/questions/272961/how-does-connectify-work)